# Restoring values of listview in Fragment

Tags: android

I am parsing a large (17mb) JSON file and displaying the results in an ExpandableListView within a fragment's onCreateView. When a user clicks a list item the main fragment is replaced.

The problem is when the user presses back, the previous fragment on stack (the expandablelistview) again parses the large JSON file and displays the results.

Is there a way to prevent the fragment from creating the view again from scratch? Or is holding those many values in the fragment impossible? I want the user to be back from where they clicked the list item.

Inside the main activity's onCreate

```
        if (null == savedInstanceState) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.root_layout, RageComicListFragment.newInstance(), "ragecomiclist")
                .commit();
    }
```

And onClick

```
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.root_layout, detailsFragment, "rageComicDetails")
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

Comment: Did you try just add() second fragment, not replace? And after onBackPressed() clicked, first fragment will be with save position and data

Comment: @Michael this will also render both fragments, one on top of the other.

Comment: "I want the user to be back from where they clicked the list item." Do you mean that you want the list to be scrolled to the same position? If so you should save this state information in onSaveInstanceState().

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, that's what i want to happen. Although when I go back to the previous fragment, i end up having to parse the large json file again. Is there anyway to just display the already created list from before? Where could i place the json parsing to list part (currently in onCreateView)?

Comment: One solution is to store the parsed JSON in a database.